# How to add a pause/wait in the middle of a nested SCNTransaction chain

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

This question must have a very simple answer, but I couldn't find it after searching for hours. Unless I just need to manually add some timer to wait.

Basically, I have an animation sequence to move a node to a certain place, *here I want to wait 5 seconds* and then I have another animation sequence to bring the node back to its original position.

Initially, I used SCNActions, grouping some actions and then sequencing them all.  Here I just added an `SCNAction.wait(duration: 5)` and that did the trick.
However, one of the actions is to move the node 90 degrees around the X-axis and I need to simultaneously rotate around another axis as well.  The result is incorrect and I have a feeling I've run into the gimbal lock issue.

So instead of using `SCNAction.rotate(by: )` I decided to rotate using quaternions which don't have the gimbal lock problem, but then I needed to switch to using an `SCNTransaction`.
I'm nesting these transaction in the completionBlock of the previous `SCNTransaction`.
For the pause between the 2 animations, I don't have a wait action here, but I thought that just adding a transaction with a duration that does nothing will at least wait for as long.  But it doesn't.  The transaction immediately skips to the 3rd step.

So is there a simple command to tell the animation transaction to wait?
I did try to add `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { <3rd SCNTransaction here> }` and that worked, but is that really the way to do it?  I have a feeling there's something else that I just don't know that replaces `SCNAction.wait()`.

Here's my current code which does the animations correctly, except it doesn't wait where I want it to (this is an excerpt of the relevant code only):

```
[...]
        let moveSideQuat = simd_quatf(angle: -currentYRotation, axis: simd_float3(0, 0, 1))
        let moveAwaySimd = simd_float3(-20 * sinf(currentYRotation), 0, -20 * cosf(currentYRotation))
        let moveUpQuat = simd_quatf(angle: .pi/2, axis: simd_float3(1, 0, 0))
        
        let moveDownQuat = simd_quatf(angle: -.pi/2, axis: simd_float3(1, 0, 0))
        let moveTowardsQuat = simd_float3(0, 0, pivotZLocation)
        let moveBackSideQuat = simd_quatf(angle: currentYRotation, axis: simd_float3(0, 0, 1))

        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1
        baseNode?.simdOrientation = moveSideQuat * baseNode!.simdOrientation
        baseNode?.simdPosition = moveAwaySimd
        baseNode?.simdOrientation = moveUpQuat * baseNode!.simdOrientation
        
        SCNTransaction.completionBlock = {
            
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 5  // <<<--- I WANT TO WAIT HERE
            
            SCNTransaction.completionBlock = {

                SCNTransaction.begin()
                SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1

                self.baseNode?.simdOrientation = moveDownQuat * self.baseNode!.simdOrientation
                self.baseNode?.simdPosition = moveTowardsQuat
                self.baseNode?.simdOrientation = moveBackSideQuat * self.baseNode!.simdOrientation


                SCNTransaction.commit()
            }
            
            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }
        
        SCNTransaction.commit()
[...]
```

In the 2nd completion block, after the `animationDuration = 5` I even tried to add a simple assignment for the node's simdPosition, basically leaving it in the same position in the hope to trick the sequence to take 5 seconds to basically do nothing, but it still skipped to the next completionBlock.

So is the `asyncAfter` actually the way to go or am I missing something else?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think `asyncAfter` is *not* the way to go?

Comment: what, if you create a dummy variable, like "var dummyFloat = 0.0" and then you change its value up to 1.0 during the 5 seconds you need?

Comment: @Sweeper I simply came from `SCNAction`s which had a very convenient `wait` action so I thought there may be an equivalent for `SCNTransaction`.  But you're right, I implemented it with `asyncAfter` and it works just fine.  You can write that as an answer and I'll upvote it.   
@ZAY thanks, but that doesn't cause the "animation" to take 5 seconds. I guess if it figures there's nothing to actually animate then it does whatever needs to be done immediately.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about this again, can't you still use `SCNAction`s for everything else, and use a `SCNTransaction` for just the rotation part of the animation? That is, put the transaction in the `SCNAction.run` block. Don't know about you, but I think that looks nicer overall.

Comment: @Sweeper, thanks for your follow-up.  Not sure I follow your suggestion.  All that I do are 2 rotations with a translation (position change) in between then a pause and then the inverse to return back to the original position.  I need both rotations and translation to move in a single smooth animation. So are you suggesting to have 3 `SCNAction`s, the 1st and 3rd will include an `SCNTransaction` and the middle one will be a `wait` action?  Can I do that?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised all the animations you do involves quaternions. I thought you also had other animations that can be written more nicely with `SCNAction`. In that case I'd probably go for `asyncAfter`. But yes, you can do 3 `SCNAction`s like that. Do note that the wait should include the duration of the first animation. As far as `SCNAction` is concerned, doing a transaction takes almost no time, and so it doesn't wait for the first animation to finish before starting the next action.

Comment: @Sweeper, thanks. Yes, indeed. When I tried working with `SCNAction` I used the `group` action to run those actions that I wanted to take place simultaneously and I then used the `sequence` action to run those groups one after another with the `wait` action in between. That worked fine, except I had to switch to quaternions. Again, you can write an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `asyncAfter` to wait is fine. That is the purpose of this method, after all.

Creating an empty transaction with the duration of 5 seconds doesn't work because SceneKit can easily see that you haven't changed anything, and knows that the animation can complete immediately. You can hide a node somewhere in the scene and animate that node for 5 seconds, but that feels way more like a hack.

If you want, you can still use `SCNAction`s for the rest of your animations, and just use `SCNTransaction` for the ones that need the quaternions. For example:

```
let step1 = SCNAction.group([
    SCNAction.run {
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1
        // do rotations here with quaternions...
        SCNTransaction.commit()
    },
    SCNAction.move(to: /* destination */, duration: 1)
])

let step2 = SCNAction.wait(duration: 5)

let step3 = SCNAction.group([
    SCNAction.run {
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1
        // rotate back...
        SCNTransaction.commit()
    },
    SCNAction.move(to: /* origin */, duration: 1)
])

let entireAction = SCNAction.sequence([
    step1, step2, step3
])
```